# Error permisos al mover directorio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net

Llevo intentado solucionar este error desde hace tiempo pero no encuentro la solución.

---

### Codigo

```
public static void PermDirectory(string perms)
{
     var directory = new DirectoryInfo(perms){ Attributes = FileAttributes.Normal };
     foreach (var info in directory.GetFileSystemInfos("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
     {
         info.Attributes = FileAttributes.Normal;
     }
}

public static void DeleteDirectory(string path)
{
     var directory = new DirectoryInfo(path) { Attributes = FileAttributes.Normal };
     foreach (var info in directory.GetFileSystemInfos("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
     {
        info.Attributes = FileAttributes.Normal;
     }
     directory.Delete(true);
}

....

if (Directory.Exists(dir_instancias_temp))
{
      DeleteDirectory(dir_instancias_temp);
}
string perms = dir_instancias_skyblock;
PermDirectory(perms);
Directory.Move(dir_instancias_skyblock, dir_instancias_temp);
string path = dir_instancias_temp;
DeleteDirectory(path);
```

---

### Error

> System.IO.IOException: Acceso denegado a la ruta de acceso 
>       'C:\Users\gonfe\Desktop\launcher\instancias\Skyblock'.
>       at System.IO.Directory.InternalMove(String sourceDirName, String 
>       destDirName, Boolean checkHost)
>       at System.IO.Directory.Move(String sourceDirName, String destDirName)
>       at Launcher_Empire_Islands.page_server_skyblock_islands.page_server_skyblock_islands_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
>       at System.Windows.Forms.UserControl.OnLoad(EventArgs e) 
>       at System.Windows.Forms.UserControl.OnCreateControl()
>       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
>       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl()
>       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.SetVisibleCore(Boolean value)
>       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.set_Visible(Boolean value)
>       at Launcher_Empire_Islands.page_servidores.imagen_skyblock_islands_Click(Object 
>       sender, EventArgs e)
>       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
>       at Bunifu.Framework.UI.BunifuImageButton.OnClick(EventArgs e)
>       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, 
>       Int32 clicks)
>       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
>       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
>       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
>       at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr 
>       wparam, IntPtr lparam)

Comment: Una opción que lo soluciona es ejecutar como administrador el programa, pero me gustaría que el programa pidiera permisos de administrador cuando los necesitara.

Comment: ¿Son carpetas en local o en red?

Comment: Mira [esto](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/105506/Getting-Elevated-Privileges-on-Demand-using-C) a ver si es lo que necesitas

Comment: Mira esto también para pedir permisos de administrador: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7666408/how-to-request-administrator-permissions-when-the-program-starts

Comment: Lo que debes hacer es dar tal como te dice el error permisos a la carpeta de otro modo por mas que ejecutes en modo administrador cuando lo pases a un ambiente real te saldrá el error.

Comment: @PHX255 Son carpetas en local

Comment: El problema es que no se como hacer para darle permisos a la carpeta @bercklynCarlosviza

Comment: nadie tiene una solución?